# Android - Converting Bitmap to string to be included in multipart request

Tags: java, android, http, bitmap, multipart

I'm trying to convert a Bitmap to String that I can include in my multipart HTTP request, I have to construct the request body manually and my problem is that when I convert the Bitmap to byte array and then from byte array to String I seem to lose the integrity of the file structure. How can I convert the Bitmap to String without damaging the file structure?

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getData());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
String s = new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: `I seem to lose the integrity of the file structure.` ? A file? You were talking about a bitmap. Especially when you use multipart upload then do not base64 encode. Just send the file as is.

Comment: In my case it's a bitmap, but I assumed uploading a file or a bitmap should be the same. 
Got any example how to send the file as is?

Comment: `data.getData()`. What is that? A filename?

Comment: It is the URI of the resource, the path to the file.

Comment: So then you want to upload a file. Why are you saying that you want to upload a bitmap then?

Comment: I meant a bitmap file.

Comment: One does not see so often .bmp files on an android device. I only .jpg and .png. So very special indeed. And what does the server expect? Or doesn't it matter? Will it accept any file? Do you have to provide a filename?

Comment: The server takes the payload as it is and saves it into a file, my problem is when I convert from byte array to string.

Comment: No you don't need a byte array. There is an OutputStream if you do a multipart upload. You open a FileInputStream on the filename and read chucks in from input and write to output in a loop. And don't use bitmap factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Bitmap to String with Base64
Try this ...

```
public String convertBitmapToString(final Bitmap pBitmap){
    final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    final byte [] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    final String string = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT); 
    return string;
}
```

Or if you can't use base64, try this

```
 try {
     String s = new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: The problem is that the web service is expecting the input as byte structure, I tried base64 and the service didn't decode it.

I have no control over the service so I have to solve this on my side.